# Log how many items have been impacted in a Spring/Hibernate transaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this method that is called from another service:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void execute(String sql) {
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Basically the client loads multiple sql files and run each sql file in a new transaction, in order to not impact other files execution.

For example this is an example of an sql file, that is cleaning up some data:

```
begin;
   delete from table t where t.created_at < current_date - interval '2 month';
commit;
```

What I'm trying to do is to log, the outcome of each transaction. For example here, I want to display how many records were deleted. How can I do that from Spring ? I know that you can log something more specific with:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=TRACE
```

, but still I cannot see any outcome. This reveals information about sql that will run and when transaction started/ended.

Second solution was to check the result of:

```
int count = query.executeUpdate();
```

, but count is 0, even though the sql code got executed and deletes hundreds of rows.

Thanks upfront for the suggestions !

Comment: `int count = query.executeUpdate();` would be the correct way to go, though I guess that you are not getting a result, because the SQL file does its own transaction

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as @XtremeBaumer correctly pointed out your script. If you just run `executeUpdate` with a delete statement it will return the number of affected rows.

But that is not what you are doing. You are executing a code block delimited by `begin` and `end`. There might be a way for such a code block to return a value, but that would need to be coded into the code block and is probably highly database specific.

Comment: Ok I see. I've started with postgreSQL transaction in the file, because there could be multiple instructions there. In this is example is just one delete, but in other files can be multiple deletes. Ok then, so if I want to know the impact of the execution, this is more database specific, then doing it from Spring/Java code. Thanks ! I was hoping that I can find somehow the output from Java..